# AutoFill using the Range Object VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to use VBA to automate filling cells with formulas, I have managed to pull my formulas in the cells properly, although I seem to be unable to either figure the proper way to use .range or maybe this isn't possible.

Is there a way that I can select an area that I'd like to fill down? 
I know that you can manually do this by selecting a set of cells and then filling down an area.

I was able to make something work by using an incredibly inefficient loop, but I know there's a better way to do this.

The code that I would have thought would make this work is

```vb
Worksheets("sheet1").range("K1:K4", "K5:K" & lastrow).filldown
```

but this doesn't do anything but repeat the data in K1 down.

Comment: Filldown is based on the top cell, what are you trying to do - copy four cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use the `AutoFill` Property of Range to drag the Formulas Down.**

**Code:**

```
Sub fill()

LastRow = 19

With Worksheets("sheet1")

    .Range("K1:K4").AutoFill Destination:=Range("K1:K" & LastRow), Type:=xlFillDefault

End With

End Sub
```

**Working:**

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your help very much! I knew there had to be a more simple way to approach this.